# $E[\sum_{i=1}^M X_i] = E[M]E[X_1]$?

Tags: expected-value

If $M, X_1, X_2, ...$ are id similarly distributed, then why is

$$E[\sum_{i=1}^M X_i] = E[M]E[X_1]$$

I don't understand what it means to sum with regards to a random variable $M$?

Comment: Have you learnt about conditional expectation?  What happens if you condition on $M $?

Comment: @probabilityislogic Why is this related to conditional expectation? Do you mean to consider $P(X_i | M)$?

Comment: @probabilityislogic If you look at the 110 questions that the OP has posted (hardly any of which have been answered to the satisfaction of the OP; _very_ few accepted answers), you will not need to ask your first question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming:

- $X_{i}$ are iid
- $X_{i}$ and $M$ are mutually independent

Let:

$$S=\sum_{i=1}^{M}X_{i}$$

Taking the expectation:

$$E[S]=E[E[S|M]]$$

Now,

$$E[S|M]=ME[X_{i}]$$

due to the fact that if $M$ is known, you have $M$ lots of $X_{i}$ summed together.

So now we have:

$$\begin{align}
E[S]&=E[E[S|M]]\\
&=E[ME[X_{i}]]\\
&=E[M]E[X_{i}]\,\,\text{ (independence)}
\end{align}$$

With regard to "*what it means to sum with regards to a random variable $M$*", consider the following example. Imagine you are an insurer who has issued some insurance policies. Based on experience, the severity of claims on these insurance policies (how much they cost the insurer) can be modeled well by the random variable $X$. The insurer would like to know how much these policies are *expected* to cost. Obviously, the insurer needs to know how many claims there will be in order to do this. However, claims are random, in this instance following the random variable $M$. Thus, to get the cost of the policies, the insurer must sum over a random variable $M$.

Comment: I very much like this answer.  You are making a good faith effort to decipher what the OP is asking.  Most puzzling is the statement that M and the Xi are id similarly distributed. Does this that all the variables are iid or is M independent with a different distribution.

Comment: @MichaelChernick Thanks. I can only assume the OP meant the $X_{i}$ are iid and that $M$ is independent of $X_{i}$.

Comment: What's the first expectation rule $E[S]=E[E[S \mid M]]$?

Comment: @mavavilj Law of iterated expectation https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expected_value#Iterated_expectation.

Answer (score 2):

this can be solved by an application of the law of iterated expectation:

$$E(\sum_{i=1}^M X_i) = E(E(\sum_{i=1}^M X_i|M)) = E(\sum_{i=1}^M E(X_i))= E( \sum_{i=1}^M E(X_1)) = E(M)E(X_1).$$

Answer (score 1):

Let $S_M=\sum_{m=1}^{M}X_{m}$.

Consider the conditional expectation of $S_{M}$ given the value of $M$ as
\begin{eqnarray*}
% \nonumber to remove numbering (before each equation)
  E\left[S_{M}|M=m\right] &=& E\left[X_{1}+X_{2}+\cdots +X_{M}|M=m\right] \\
   &=& E\left[X_{1}+X_{2}+\cdots +X_{m}\right]\quad \mbox{ since X and M are independent RV's}\\
   &=& m E[X]\quad \mbox{ since $X_{i}'s$ are iid RV's}\\
  E\left[S_{M}\right] &=& \sum_{m}\underbrace{E\left(S_{M}|M=m\right)}_{m\cdot E[X]} P\left\{M=m\right\}\\
  &=& \sum_{m} m\cdot E[X]\cdot P\left\{M=m\right\}\\
  &=&E(X)\cdot \sum_{m}m\cdot P\left\{M=m\right\}\\
  E\left[S_{M}\right] &=& E[X]\cdot E[M]
\end{eqnarray*}